# React Native display View depending on conditional

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my render method I'd like to display one of two `View` components depending on a conditional that's in my `props`. e.g:

```
render() {
  return(
    <View>
      <View>View A</View>
      <View>View B</View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Where the conditional is `this.props.myConditional`. If `false`, show A, if `true`, show B...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy

```js
render() {
  return <View>
    {this.props.myConditional ? <View>View B</View> : <View>View A</View>}
  </View>
}
```

Comment: How about if you want to display it only if it's true and display "nothing" if not ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are Using Functional Component, The latest Approach then its much more easy as,

```
return (
<View style={Condition ? Styles.A : Styles.B}>

</View>

)
```

const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
    A: {
display:"none"
},
B:{
display:"flex"
}
}
)

Rest you have to look into functional component

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to display based on condition:

1. Inline Condition

   ```
    { (link) && 
     <Text>Read More</Text> 
    }
   ```
2. Inline Condition

   ```
   { (link) 
     ? <Text>Read More</Text> 
     : <Text>Thank you</Text> }
   ```
3. Using a function

   ```
   const Displaylink = (props) => {

     const isLink = props.isLink;
     if (isLnk) {
      return <Text>Read More</Text>;
     }
     return <Text>Thank you</Text>;
   }
   ```