# Show clear button if TextInput is not empty

Tags: react-native

I have clear button that I want to show after the user starts typing something. Right now it's showing all the time, even if the TextInput is empty, I'm new to React Native and have no idea how to start

This is my code so far:

```js
<View
  style={[
      {
          flexDirection: 'row',
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderRadius: 30,
          padding: 10,
          marginLeft: 20,
          marginRight: 20,
          // marginTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : -20,
          marginBottom: 5,
          borderColor: theme.inputBorder,
          backgroundColor: theme.insightBg,
      },
      {color: theme.primaryTextColor},
  ]}>
    <View>
        <SearchIcon
          style={{left: 2, top: 3, marginRight: 10}}
          active={theme.search.inputPlaceholder}
        />
    </View>
    <TextInput
      selectionColor="#25C0D5"
      style={[
          {
              width: '100%',
              height: 30,
              padding: 6,
              color: theme.primaryTextColor,
          },
      ]}
      value={props.search}
      placeholderTextColor={theme.search.inputPlaceholder}
      placeholder="Search Offer Groups"
      returnKeyType={'search'}
      autoCapitalize="none"
      autoCorrect={false}
      onSubmitEditing={(e) => props.setSearch(e.nativeEvent.text)}
      onChangeText={(text) => props.setSearchValue(text)}
      autoFocus={false}

    />
    <View style={{position:'absolute', right: 0, padding: 10, top:3}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {clearAndRefresh()}}>
            <CloseIcon
              style={{right: 0, marginRight: 10, }}
              active={theme.search.inputPlaceholder}
            />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
</View>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native display View depending on conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44256969/react-native-display-view-depending-on-conditional)

Comment: perfect, thank you!